# $\psi$ Represents amplitude of electron wave and $\psi^2$ represents electron density in a given space. How?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure

The $\psi$ represents amplitude of electron wave. So it's dimension should be $\left[L\right] $. But $\psi^2$ represents density of electrons in a given space. So it's dimension should be $\left[ML^{-3}\right]$.
Now $\left[L\right]^2 \neq \left[ML^{-3}\right] $.

So what's wrong with the concept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically everything is wrong, unfortunately.

$\psi^2$ isn't a mass density, it's a [**probability density**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). So there is no point in which you should be getting units of mass. As porphyrin pointed out, the units of $\psi^2$ (and hence $\psi$) will depend on the system which you are looking at.

Next, $\psi$ isn't a length amplitude. In fact, it's not an amplitude at all. When people talk about wavefunctions being amplitudes, what they are usually talking about is the *coefficients* of the basis states of $\psi$. For example, if you express $\psi$ as a linear combination $c_1\phi_1 + c_2\phi_2 + \cdots$, then the $c_i$'s are called amplitudes. But they aren't length amplitudes of some wave, they're [**probability amplitudes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude).

Wikipedia's pages (linked above) describe the concepts in far greater details, and you will also see these terms arise frequently when reading about QM.

Answer (score 3):

The wavefunctions are normal mathematical functions; nothing special. The dimensions of $\psi$ depend on the problem. A particle in a 1D box has the normalised wavefunction  $\displaystyle \psi(x) =\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{L} \right) $ so has dimensions of $[L]^{-1/2}$. In 2 and 3 dimensions the units of $\psi$ change accordingly.

The expression $\psi(x)^*\psi(x)$ is interpreted as the probability of being in the infinitesimally thin region $x\to x+dx$ so the probability is strictly $\psi(x)^*\psi(x)dx$ which is dimensionless (as a probability should be) and has a value $0\to 1$ as the waavefunction is normalised.

This works for other measurements also, for example to find the average of the position in the box, $\displaystyle \langle x \rangle=\int_0^L \psi(x)x\psi(x)dx=\frac{L}{2}$  (for all $n>0$) which you can see by looking at the dimensions before integrating (don't forget to include dx), and similarly the average of the square of the position is $\displaystyle \langle x^2 \rangle=\int_0^L \psi(x)x^2\psi(x)dx$ which you can see has dimensions of $[L]^2$. For the first level, $n=1$ the exact result is $L^2(1/3-1/(2\pi^2))$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest wave function of the Hydrogen atom in the $\ce{1s}$ state is :  $$\ce{\Psi _{1s} =  \pi^{-1/2}} ·(1/a_o)^{3/2} · e^{-{r/a_o}}$$ It has a dimension  $\ce{L^{-3/2}}$